# FastCGI and Unicode

Tags: c, unicode, fastcgi

I am wondering if Fastcgi supports unicode functions like wprintf. I receive  a buffer via fread and get char* that has unicode characters in it. I mean bytes with value above 128 . How do I process them inside fastcgi main function. A call to mbstowcs fails.

I meant that I was using the FastCGI Developers Kit library.  A java client is sending data encoded with UTF-8 , I decoded it server side using mbstring functions in php , but what is the equivalent of that gcc . What ever it is does not seem to work inside the FastCGI amin function. I looked at Fascgipp but I dont know how much it is used and how stable it is . Further I dont find lugging a huge library like boost justified for a small utility.

Answer (score 3):

If you need Unicode, use UTF-8 and not "wide" characters. They are much more suitable for the web.

Answer (score 2):

Fastcgi is protocol not an API. 
So it depend on the library you are choosing. 
Yes see library 
http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/

Answer (score 0):

> I receive a buffer via fread and get char* that has unicode characters in it. I mean bytes with value above 128 .

Unicode is not the only encoding that has bytes above 128 in it. In fact, most other encodings do. You need to find out which encoding is exactly used in your web application. In any case, I don't think wprintf is going to be useful to you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

FastCGI expects a byte stream, so your safest bet is UTF-8.
That being said, the program should work with non-UTF-8 input; iconv is ideal for this.

You can use wprintf, but only in the form of wsnprintf, after which buffer contents are converted to UTF-8 and then written to the correct FCGI stream.